# How to add pop() extension to Array in swift?

Tags: swift

How do I extend an Array in swift?

I want to say

```
extension Array
{
    func pop() -> AnyObject
    {
        let out = self.last
        self.removeLast()
        return out
    }
}
```

but the compiler does not like self.removeLast() or return out

Comment: I just copied that into playground, and as you said the compiler wasn't happy...but then when I retyped the line it was fine. the only issue with this i see is can you safely cast the return value if the list has multiple types?

Comment: removeLast() already returns the value it removes. You don’t have to save it in a temporary variable or anything. Your pop() is functionally equivalent to removeLast().

Answer (score 1):

As @i40West points out, `removeLast` *is* essentially a pop.  That said, if you wanted to fix the compiler issues with the original code:

1. The array might not contain class references so `AnyObject` wouldn’t work.  You could replace that with `Any` (which can contain classes, structs or enums), but better to return an `Element`, which is what an instance of `Array` typealiases for whatever it actually contains.
2. `self.last` returns an optional (in case the array is empty).  You could choose to return an optional from `pop` similar to `last`, or just assert if the array is empty similar to `removeLast`.
3. Since `pop` is modifying `self` (it removes an entry) and `Array` is a struct, you need to mark the function as `mutating`.

So the full version, assuming `removeLast` didn’t return a value, could be something like:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        precondition(self.startIndex != self.endIndex, "Attempt to pop from an empty array")
        let out = self.last
        self.removeLast()
        return out!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use AnyObject. Have you learned generics?
Try:

```
    extension Array
    {
        func pop() -> T
        {
            let out = self.last
            self.removeLast()
            return out
        }
    }
```